# How can I count values in a range that are greater, equal, less than values in a another range in Excel?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I think my question is really basic but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I have a table "Matches" that shows a home team, an away team, the round and the score. Like this:

```
Round | HomeTeam | HTGoals | ATGoals | AwayTeam
-----------------------------------------------
1     | team1    |  1      | 0       | team4
1     | team2    |  1      | 1       | team5
1     | team3    |  0      | 1       | team6
2     | team4    |  3      | 0       | team1
2     | team5    |  2      | 0       | team2
2     | team6    |  2      | 0       | team3
-----------------------------------------------
```

(Sorry I can't paste images yet)

I need a second table with Home Team victories, away team victories, and ties, like this:

```
      |Home|Tie|Away
---------------------
Round1|1   |1  |1
Round2|3   |0  |0
```

But I can't find a formula that will do that comparison automatically. I tried this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A;1;C:C;">"&D:D)
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you know if there is a way to COUNT the times one range of values (in this case HTgoals) is greater than another range of values (in this case ATGoals) comparing each cell in the first range with the respective cell in the next range?

One more thing, without considering the round, if I just verify the goal comparison, I found a solution that is everywhere:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C:C>D:D))
```

And it works for ">" and "<" but it doesn't for "=" so it is not working for me.

I have two possible solutions that I'm trying to avoid but if there is no formula, please let me know.

1- I can create an extra column that compares the scores with 3 IF, ElseIF, ELSE that replies "HW", "AW" or "TIE". and then do COUNTIFS() with the round and the resuls. (I'm trying to avoid this one because my data is coming form a database)

2- I can go ahead and make a procedure in my database (mySQL) which I'm also trying to avoid because I would end up having tons and tons of store procedures for each competition. I need to have that logic in diferent workspaces (Or spreadsheets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SumProduct will work:

```
      |Home|Tie|Away
---------------------
Round1|a   |b  |c
Round2|3   |0  |0

a: =SUMPRODUCT(((A:A=1)*(C:C>D:D)))  
b: =SUMPRODUCT(((A:A=1)*(C:C=D:D)))  
c: =SUMPRODUCT(((A:A=1)*(C:C<D:D)))
```

I'll let you figure out Round2

Comment: The `--` is not needed if you are multiplying the two together, only if you separate the two with `,`

Comment: Also not to nit pick but one should avoid full column references with SUMPRODUCT, as it will iterate through the whole column all 1.04 million rows.  It will slow down the calculations.

Comment: Yeah that too I had A2:A7 and rest of the columns, but I was trying to follow OP's format.  OP please take note on Scott's comment

Comment: This worked great. What if the source data is a different sheet? I'm trying to replicat the formula adding "Sheet2!" before each range but it does not work anymore.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(((Sheet2!A2:A7=1)*(Sheet2!C2:C7>Sheet2!D2:D7))).  Every range needs to reference to the sheetname.  Also, please look at Scott's comment to avoid using (A:A) but specified range instead.

Answer (score 2):

Three formula:

Home:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=G2)*($C$2:$C$7> $D$2:$D$7))
```

Tie:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=G2)*($C$2:$C$7= $D$2:$D$7))
```

Away:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=G2)*($C$2:$C$7< $D$2:$D$7))
```

[image]

---

You can also use this one array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=$G2)*(CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:A),--($C$2:$C$7> $D$2:$D$7),--($C$2:$C$7= $D$2:$D$7),--($C$2:$C$7< $D$2:$D$7))))
```

Put it in H2, hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter, then copy/drag over and down.

[image]